# Detect when a bullet rigidbody is on ground

Tags: physics, ogre, bullet-physics

I have a rigidbody that is on top of a plane or another rigidbody. How do I check if said rigidbody is on top of it?

I tried to check the Y-part of the velocity but it is never 0, it is always a small value.

What would be the best way to detect this?

Comment: "it is always a small value" Could it be as simple as checking to see if the value is less than .5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a ray test straight down from the rigid body and test the distance of the ray hit.

One way is to simply use the rigid body position and subtract 10,000 or some arbitrary number to get a destination for the ray test.

```
btVector3 btFrom(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
btVector3 btTo(pos.x, -10000.0, pos.z);
btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback res(btFrom, btTo);

btWorld->rayTest(btFrom, btTo, res); // m_btWorld is btDiscreteDynamicsWorld

if(res.hasHit()){
    /* Use Ogre::Vector3::squaredDistance() to find the difference from the rigid body to the ray hit */
}
```

Comment: `rayTest` isn't detecting a rigidbody, just a plane. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you setting the mask and group when you add collision objects and rigid bodies? For rigid bodies, I leave them as default, and anything else uses group 2 and a mask of 1, like so: btWorld->addCollisionObject(obj, 2, 1);

Comment: If you use this method I would suggest a much smaller "to" vector. Maybe something like -1, otherwise you will have to call the distance function much more than necessary (although it probably doesn't consume much CPU time). You could however use a larger vector if you wanted to do something like play an animation in preparation for the rigidbody/ground collision (like if you needed a character to brace themselves for impact).

Comment: I'm not sure how Ogre works, but you might only be getting the first collision of the ray rather than all of them. If that is the case you could be getting a hit on the collider attached to the rigid body since it is closer than the ground.

Comment: btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback retrieves the first collision in the physics world. If you want to get all of the collisions from a ray, you can subclass RayResultCallback and store a list of collisions. In my case the player's rigid body isn't included in the ray test because it is added without a group and mask (kind of odd).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, it to check the normal of the collision. If the y value of the normal is very high then it is more flat (facing upwards). You can also change the threshold you allow for larger or smaller slopes.

```
//Go through collisions
int numManifolds = btDispatcher->getNumManifolds();
    for (int i = 0; i < numManifolds; i++)
    {
        btPersistentManifold* contactManifold = btWorld->getDispatcher()->getManifoldByIndexInternal(i);
        btCollisionObject* obA = const_cast<btCollisionObject*>(contactManifold->getBody0());
        btCollisionObject* obB = const_cast<btCollisionObject*>(contactManifold->getBody1());

        GameObject* gameObjA = static_cast<GameObject*>(obA->getUserPointer());
        GameObject* gameObjB = static_cast<GameObject*>(obB->getUserPointer());
        if (gameObjA->name == "Camera" || gameObjB->name == "Camera" /*have some way to check if one of the objects is the rigidbody you want */) {
            int numContacts = contactManifold->getNumContacts();
            for (int j = 0; j < numContacts; j++)
            {
                btManifoldPoint& pt = contactManifold->getContactPoint(j);
                if (pt.getDistance() < 0.f)
                {

                    glm::vec3 normal;


                    if (gameObjB->name == "Camera") //Check each object to see if it's the rigid body and determine the correct normal.
                        normal = -pt.m_normalWorldOnB;
                    else
                        normal = pt.m_normalWorldOnB;


                    if (normal.y > 0.4f /*put the threshold here */) {
                        //The character controller is on the ground
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```